# passing variables into dynamically generated classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to DRY my code by writing a dynamically generated class methods.

What I want is to have multiple error classes and I have the following codes

ruby

```
class ChatPolicy::Error < StandardError
ERROR_CLASSES = [
    { class_name: 'UserBlacklisted', message: 'Message 1' },
    { class_name: 'UserSuspended', message: 'Message 2' },
    { class_name: 'UserNotEligibleToRent', message: 'Message 3' },
    { class_name: 'MembershipTierNotAllowed', message: 'Message 4' }
]

ERROR_CLASSES.each do |cls|
    Object.const_set(cls[:class_name], Class.new {
        attr_reader :object

        def initialize(object)
            @object = object
            @message = cls[:message]
        end
    })
end
end
```

However, since in the `Class.new {}` block, the variable cannot be passed in. I can't initialize the message variable. I am wondering how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a method with `def`, you cannot refer to local variables from the outer scope inside the method definition, i.e. the `cls` variable in the `initialize` method.

You *can* refer to such local variables from inside a block, and you can use a block to create a method with [`define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method).

So in your example you can get it working by changing the line

```
def initialize(object)
```

to

```
define_method(:initialize) do |object|
```

Now since the method body is a block you can refer to `cls` inside the body.

Comment: Thanks @matt. It works now but there is a warning from console. `1: warning: toplevel constant UserSuspended referenced by ChatPolicy::Error::UserSuspended` I wonder how it can be solved?

Comment: **update** Actually it doesn't work because when I typed `ChatPolicy::Error::UserSuspended` in console it becomes `UserSuspended`

Comment: Found the solution, based on @mudasobwa's solution. It shouldn't need `Object.const_set` just use `const_set`

Answer (score 1):

> However, since in the `Class.new {}` block, the variable cannot be passed in.

That is not about “variable can not be passed in,” this is about “inside a block, the receiver differs and `cls` local variable can not be resolved.” There are two possible approaches to achieve the goal:

— lookup the message directly from what is visible:

```
@message = ChatPolicy::Error::ERROR_CLASSES.detect do |hash|
  hash[:class_name] == self.class.name
end[:message]
```

— or use `class_eval`:

```
ERROR_CLASSES.each do |cls|
    Object.const_set(cls[:class_name], class_eval %Q|
      Class.new {
        attr_reader :object

        def initialize(object)
            @object = object
            @message = '#{cls[:message]}' # ⇐ HERE !!!
        end
    }|)
end
```

**UPD** the approach by @matt is better; I leave this answer for historical purposes only.

Comment: Both yours and matt's solution contributed to the right solution. Thanks